# Python Encrypt PDF Simple Method AES 256

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, encryption, pypdf

I have used this method to encrypt a PDF file with AES 128:

```
import PyPDF2
pdffile = open(r"input.pdf", "rb")
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))

pdfWriter.encrypt('password')
resultPDF = open(r"output.pdf", "wb")
pdfWriter.write(resultPDF)
resultPDF.close()
```

...but is there a similarly-simple way to use AES 256?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any updates on this question?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue. I use `pikepdf` to solve it.

```py
import pikepdf
with pikepdf.Pdf.open(r"input.pdf") as pdf:
    pdf.save(r"output.pdf", encryption=pikepdf.Encryption(
        owner='password', user='password'))
```

By default, `pikepdf` use AES-256 to encrypt.

Comment: This is great! However, when I run the code, "out.pdf" requires a newer version of Adobe than what I have. I'm not sure if my current version of Adobe just does not handle AES-256 or if there is an option/kwarg that can adjust for the PDF version. I could not find anything in the docs.